# Forcing URL to convert 4-part unicode string to Chinese character

Tags: browser, unicode, character-encoding, cjk

My URL (which I'm passing to `twitter/share` in a query string) contains `%C2%BC%C3%BE`, the encoding for 件, but the browser decodes it as two characters ¼þ. How can I let the browser know that it should decode it as a single character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your encoding is wrong. The browser is decoding it correctly as those two characters. The correct UTF-8 bytes for U+4EF6 are E4, BB, and B6.

Comment: Where do you find out what are the correct UTF-8 bytes for a character? I searched for ages for a good reference before posting this question. And do any characters, correctly encoded, have four part UTF-8 bytes? How would I go about finding out which ones?

Comment: I looked it up here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4ef6/index.htm. All characters above U+FFFF have four bytes in UTF-8.